# How to return an array in config file in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I am trying to myconfig.php inside app/config. I want it to return this array

```
return ['default_domain_name' => 'myapp']
```

as in:   app/config/myconfig.php

I want to call it inside the middleware I created

```
class VerifyDomain
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->get('domain_name', $this->getBaseDomain());

        $company = Company::where('subdomain', $subdomain)->firstOrFail();

        $request->session()->put('subdomain', $company);

        return $next($request);
    } 

    protected function getBaseDomain()
    {
        return config('myconfig.default_domain_name', 'myapp');
    }
}
```

How do I write to return:

```
return ['default_domain_name' => 'myapp']
```

inside   app/config/myconfig.php

Thanks

Comment: what do you get if you do a `var_dump(config('myconfig'))`

Comment: @FrédéricKlee - var_dump(config('myconfig')) returns null. How do I register and reference app/config/myconfig.php.    This what I have in myconfig.php:    <?php

return [
        'default_domain_name' => 'myapp'
        ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your config looks like this:

```php
return [
    'default_domain_name' => 'myapp',
]
```

... and your config file has `myconfig.php` name...

Just call

```php
config('myconfig'); // returns ['default_domain_name' => 'myapp']
```

Comment: var_dump(config('myconfig')) returns null. How do I register and reference app/config/myconfig.php. This what I have in myconfig.php: <?php return [ 'default_domain_name' => 'myapp', ];

Comment: if your config file is in folder "config" you have nothing to do, but clear cache config maybe !?

Comment: thank you I don't know why I didn't test this maybe I'm tired.